# How to make private variable accessible in public function without using privileged member?

Tags: javascript, variables, prototype, private

I have a variable and a function

```
var a=[];
function b(){}
```

I want to make them accessible inside a constructor and its prototype.

```
function Fnctn()
{
    //a and b is accessible here
}
Fnctn.prototype={
    one:function()
    {
        //a and b is accessible here
    },
    two:function()
    {
        //a and b is accessible here
    },
    …
    n:function()
    {
        //a and b is accessible here
    }
}
//a and b is not accessible to the user
```

The first solution that I found was to use a privileged member inside the constructor

```
function Fnctn()
{
    var a=[];
    function b(){}
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
}
```

Now a and b is accessible in the prototype with this.a and this.b but they are also accessible to the user.
The second solution that I found was

```
function Fnctn()
{
    var a=[];
    function b(){}
    //a and b is accessible here
    this.one=function()
    {
        //a and b is accessible here
    };
    this.two=function()
    {
        //a and b is accessible here
    };
    …
    this.n=function()
    {
        //a and b is accessible here
    };
}
//a and b is not accessible to the user
```

This solution does what I want but as said in [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/07/05/private-members-in-javascript/) it need more memory and time. Thus this two solutions are not suitable.
So, how can I do this?
Rephrasing the question: I want to know if there are any other way (if yes then what) available to do it or is this the only way?
I would like to know about any third method if available.

Note: var a is not limited to an Array. It can be anything (String, Number etc.).

Comment: More memory and time than what? And how much? $10 is more than $9, but it's cheap for a Ferrari. ;-) Implement your solution so it has the functionality you need. Then, **if** you have memory or storage issues, do something. Otherwise, be happy with what you have (i.e. avoid premature optimisation).

Comment: I'm also pretty sure you don't want to share `[]` through prototype as it will act like *static* variable (*static* as in the classes oriented language).

Comment: You appear to know how to do it, but don't want to use the scheme shown to you in the article you referenced.  That's how you do it.  There is no other magic way.  Either accept that design and any consequences of that design or not.

Comment: Even the author of that article says "Not necessarily very much [memory and time], considering modern PCs, but some." There is no doubt this approach uses more memory (some small, most likely insignificantly larger amount), but what I can't see is how it uses more time. And the author does not elaborate on the "time" aspect. If anything, it should be faster, to the extent prototypes do not have to be traversed. Again, though, this difference is likely to be trivial unless you are building a million of these objects. And what's the alternative?